# Check if a name contains more than one title

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I want to build a query to identify is there more than one titles in one name.

> Eg: Mr A Cohen Mrs B Cohen

Title list:

> ('Mr', 'Mr.', 'Mrs', 'Mrs.', 'Miss', 'Miss.', 'Other', 'Ms', 'Ms.')

I can check for the first title using below:

```
 IF (SUBSTRING(@Name, 0, CHARINDEX(' ', @Name)) NOT IN 
    ('Mr', 'Mr.', 'Mrs', 'Mrs.', 'Miss', 'Miss.', 'Other', 'Ms', 'Ms.'))
```

But I'm stuck on checking for the 2nd title.

I can get the part without the 1st title using below code:

```
LTRIM(STUFF(@Name, CHARINDEX(Title, @Name), LEN(Title), ''))
```

This gives me the output as `'A Cohen Mrs B Cohen'`. From this I want to check if any of those title exists inside this output.

I know I can go for multiple `LIKE` operators for each title, but I'm looking for something tidier.

Comment: It won't be the fastest query, but you could put the titles in a table variable, join with like and group by/having count > 1.

Comment: Is Mr Smith and Mr Cohen one title or two ?

Comment: Why not just find matches that have a space and then the title (i.e. ` Mr`), which would only return where there is a second title?

Comment: @JohnCappelletti That's two. I checking for combined names.

Comment: Tip: Beware of solutions that don't handle names like "Missy Brother", "Adelaide Salmissra" and "Jim-Bob Strother" properly, especially in combination with other names.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `JOIN` and a derived table:

```
select t.name, count(*) as num_titles
from t join
     (values ('Mr'), ('Mr.'), ('Mrs'), ('Mrs.'), ('Miss'), ('Miss.'), ('Other'), ('Ms'), ('Ms.')
     ) v(title)
     on name like '%' + v.title + '%'
group by t.name
having count(*) >= 2;
```

Note that this will necessarily find duplicates for "Mr.", "Mrs", "Mrs.", "Miss.", and "Ms." because these have *other* titles that match the same title (such as "Mr").  This would appear to meet the conditions that you specify.

To prevent this, you might want to require a space after the title.  If so, use:

```
     on name like '%' + v.title + ' %'
```

Comment: Agreed, I would just add the trailing space to items without the period i.e.  ('Mr ')

Comment: You can't use the alias `num_titles` in the `HAVING` clause instead of `COUNT(*)`. Also what if `Mr` exists twice? it should be counted.

Comment: *"You can't use the alias num_titles in the HAVING clause instead of COUNT(*)"* @Sami  true that is MySQL syntax where it is allowed to use a alias in the having clause that is what you get when you know alot of databases systems.. You start mixing things up sometimes.

Comment: @RaymondNijland Like I don't know that! The comment is a note for Gordon to edit his question nothing more, cause I won't edit his code, it's the only thing I never touch it. Still if `Mr` exists twice or >2 that will return the wrong results. See  John Cappelletti comment and the reply of the OP.

Comment: @Sami mine comment was more meant for the general readers so Gordon didn't get unnecessary downvotes for that syntax when others would read your comment that the query is "totally invalid".. *"The comment is a note for Gordon to edit his question nothing more, cause I won't edit his code, it's the only thing I never touch it"* it's fine to edit those small syntax "typos" pretty sure Gordon does not mind that i changed it.

Comment: This answer and @Martin's comment in question together helped me to build the working solution. Thanks guys!